# Getting error in higher environment org - Test Environment (SIT), but not in development environment

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform

I am facing a weird issue with lightning record edit form that was not coming till yesterday and is coming only in SIT and not in the lower environment developer org.

The issue is when a user selects something out of the suggestion in lightning:inputfield text box a error pops in, in the screen. (The suggestions are coming from browser cache memory)

Attatching the snapshot
[image]

After selecting any value out of the suggestions it throws the below error

[image]

I am unable to figure out how come the same steps produces error in one environment and not in another

Comment: Without any code we can't tell anything. What's running in the onchange event of your text field?

Comment: Could be connected to: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=924783